# Multiple web sites and/or certificates in IIS7.5

Tags: iis, https, certificate

I currently have a web site (Windows 2008 R2, IIS 7.5) in https that hosts applications for several coountries. I have one web server certificate for domain name let's say a.com. Different countries reaches their web site with https://abc.com/FR, https://abc.com/US, https://abc.com/UK... FR, US and UK are just directories below the web root folder.

Now I would like to setup an environment where I can use certificates (and DNS names) like us.abc.com, fr.abc.com and uk.abc.com. Make several DNS entries pointing to same IP is not a problem. Do I need 3 web certficates associated with each domain names (wildcard certificates are not an option in my company) and make 3 different web sites listening to different ports? How to not force the user to enter an SSL port different from 443 ? I could even need in addition to us.abc.com, fr.abc.com and uk.abc.com a generic (not including the country name -> something like generic.abc.com) certificate where I could continue to work as before!

Answer (score 0):

If you do 3 ip addresses, you can use a standard SSL certificate for each ip address. This can get complicated with having to manage multiple certificates.

Or you could get a [subject alternative name certificate (SAN certificate)](http://www.ssl.com/certificates/ucc) that will allow you to have multiple domains on a single certificate. You can then use 1 ip address for the 3 domains, or export this certificate onto the 3 ip addresses if that is the path you want to take. Also, you can easily create a certificate signing request that contains multiple domains on Windows using [SSLTools Manager](http://www.ssltools.com/manager).